# Disable option that block repetitive alert in FireFox

Tags: firefox

I´m developing for web and my application use some alerts to show error messages but in firefox 4 if I show the alert more than one time, the option for blocking repetitive alert dialogs will appear, but if I check the option, I can not continue to do the next action.

Can you tell me how to hide the option in alert ? Is there any possibility  with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's the user's option not yours.

***Edit***: You can show error messages in a unique way using [JQuery UI's dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). This is not a standard popup box and is a nice way to display the error.

Another alternative is to have a div that you display errors in and show/hide it. This is less distracting since it shows all the errors at once.

Comment: but exist some idea of how to disable this?

Comment: @user611986 You can't, it's part of the Firefox code and not interface-able with standard JavaScript. You would literally have to create an extension, which even then I'm fairly sure that's not feasible. I have given you some alternatives to what you want to do inline.

Comment: Oh, an extension could get rid of that checkbox.  Now getting the user to install that extension....

Comment: @Boris Never said it was reasonable, merely that it's potentially feasible